# Counting expenses for categories stored in tree like array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an app where users can store their expenses and assign it to categories. Categories have tree structure, without depth limit and users can assign expense to any category (children, parent or middle). What I want to do is to count sum of expenses for all categories in tree structure. Lets simplify things and assume I have array with categories:

```php
$categories = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Car',
        'expenses_sum' => 0,
        'subcategories' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Gas',
                'expenses_sum' => 0,
                'subcategories' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => 3,
                        'name' => 'Orlen',
                        'expenses_sum' => 300,
                        'subcategories' => [
                            0 => [
                                'id' => 4,
                                'name' => 'Orlen A',
                                'expenses_sum' => 100,
                                'subcategories' => []
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'id' => 5,
                                'name' => 'Orlen B',
                                'expenses_sum' => 100,
                                'subcategories' => []
                            ], 
                        ],
                    ],                                               
                ],
            ],                    
        ],
    ],       
];
```

What I want do do is to go to the deepest level ("Orlen A" and "Orlen B"), sum expenses from that level, add it to the parent level ("Orlen") and store as the new "expenses_sum", so it should be: 100 + 100 + 300 = 500 and repeat it to the top level.

My code to do that looks like this:

```php
function sumCategory(&$category) {
    if (isset($category['subcategories'])) {
        foreach ($category['subcategories'] as $subCategory) {
            $subCategory['expenses_sum'] = sumCategory($subCategory);
            $category['expenses_sum'] += $subCategory['expenses_sum'];
        }
    }

    return $category['expenses_sum'];
}


foreach ($categories as $index => $category) {
    $categories[$index]['expenses_sum'] = sumCategory($category);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($categories);
echo '</pre>';
```

Code counts properly sum at all levels, but the problem is that finally I got $categories array with modfied only "expenses_sum" at the top level and categories in the middle stays not modified. I tried to pass $categories to function by refference, but it doesnt help. Any tips what should I correct?

I have simplified problem, so you can easily grab all above code to test things on your own.

To clarify things: at the end I expect my array will be as follow:

```php
$categories = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Car',
        'expenses_sum' => 500, //500 + 0
        'subcategories' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Gas',
                'expenses_sum' => 500, //500 + 0 
                'subcategories' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => 3,
                        'name' => 'Orlen',
                        'expenses_sum' => 500, //100 + 100 + 300
                        'subcategories' => [
                            0 => [
                                'id' => 4,
                                'name' => 'Orlen A',
                                'expenses_sum' => 100,
                                'subcategories' => []
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'id' => 5,
                                'name' => 'Orlen B',
                                'expenses_sum' => 100,
                                'subcategories' => []
                            ], 
                        ],
                    ],                                               
                ],
            ],                    
        ],
    ],       
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categories = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Car',
        'expenses_sum' => 0,
        'subcategories' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Gas',
                'expenses_sum' => 0,
                'subcategories' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => 3,
                        'name' => 'Orlen',
                        'expenses_sum' => 300,
                        'subcategories' => [
                            0 => [
                                'id' => 4,
                                'name' => 'Orlen A',
                                'expenses_sum' => 100,
                                'subcategories' => []
                            ],
                            1 => [
                                'id' => 5,
                                'name' => 'Orlen B',
                                'expenses_sum' => 100,
                                'subcategories' => []
                            ], 
                        ],
                    ],                                               
                ],
            ],                    
        ],
    ],       
];

function expensesSum($category) {
    $sum = $category['expenses_sum'] ;
    foreach($category['subcategories'] as $subCategory) {
        $sum += expensesSum($subCategory);
    }
    return $sum;
}

function calculateExpenses(&$categories) {
    foreach($categories as $index => $category) {
        // do subs first
        calculateExpenses($categories[$index]['subcategories']);
        // then parent
        $categories[$index]['expenses_sum'] = expensesSum($category);

    }
    return $categories;
}

print_r(calculateExpenses($categories));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Car
            [expenses_sum] => 500
            [subcategories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Gas
                            [expenses_sum] => 500
                            [subcategories] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => Orlen
                                            [expenses_sum] => 500
                                            [subcategories] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 4
                                                            [name] => Orlen A
                                                            [expenses_sum] => 100
                                                            [subcategories] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 5
                                                            [name] => Orlen B
                                                            [expenses_sum] => 100
                                                            [subcategories] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm :).

Answer (score -1):

```
function calculateExpenses($categories) {
    $expenses = 0;
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $expenses += $category['expenses_sum'];
        $expenses += calculateExpenses($category['subcategories']);
    }
    return $expenses;
}

echo calculateExpenses($categories);
```